# Understanding first evm word of reference types in assembly

Tags: abi, assembly, calldata, data-types, encoding

Given the following function:

```
function getArrayItems(bytes calldata) external returns (
    bytes4 _signature,
    bytes32 _wutIsThis,
    bytes32 _length,
    bytes32 _firstItem
) {
    assembly {
        _signature := calldataload(0x00) // trim the first 4 bytes
        _wutIsThis := calldataload(0x04)
        _length := calldataload(0x24)
        _firstItem := calldataload(0x44)
    }
}
```

I get the following output when I run the code in [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org) with the input `0xcafe`:

```
{   
    "0": "bytes4: _signature 0x38626302",
    "1": "bytes32: _wutIsThis 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020",
    "2": "bytes32: _length 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
    "3": "bytes32: _firstItem 0xcafe000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

I fully understand the 1st, 3rd and 4th items. `_length` was tricky, but according to the [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.5/assembly.html#conventions-in-solidity):

> The length of a dynamic array is stored at the first slot of the array and followed by the array elements.

It's the 2nd item, `_wutIsThis`, that is causing me trouble. My hunch is that it's about the data location of the array. That is, data is offset by `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`, which means that the first item of the array is located 32 bytes after the said location's position in calldata (I know, this is so meta).

Is that correct? If yes, why do we do this and where can I find some further documentation? The solidity docs on [type data location](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.5/types.html#data-location) are a bit vague and only explain that reference types must specify a keyword (`memory`, `storage` or `keyword`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that correct? If yes, why do we do this and where can I find some further documentation?

Yes, you are correct.

Transactions are encoded based on the Contract ABI Specification. It is hard to get through, but [these docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html) have all the answers to your question.

---

The transaction in question is passing in a dynamic parameter (`bytes`) as opposed to a static one (`uint`, `address`, etc.). When encoding the parameters, the EVM looks to see if the parameters are static or dynamic.

Static parameters are encoded in a fairly straightforward manner--they are converted to their hex representation and then concatenated into the input data hex string.

Dynamic values are more interesting. Use [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types) section of the docs to fully understand, but the idea is that the encoded data is the *location of the data*. The encoded data itself is then concatenated to the end of the input data hex string, *after* all of the dynamic types. For dynamic types, the length of the parameter is then included, followed by the data itself.

Breaking down the transaction you posted:

> 0x3862630200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002cafe000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

`0x38626302`

This is the method ID of the function called (in this case, `getArrayItems(bytes)`)

`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020`

This is the *location* of the first (dynamic) parameter. This is the location where `calldata` lives, but is not the data itself.

`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002`

This is the length of the dynamic `calldata`. In this case, the length is 2 *because of the way `bytes` works*. The EVM sees your `0xcafe` as [`0xca`],[`0xfe`], which is why the length is 2 even though there is only one parameter passed in.

`cafe000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

The data passed into `calldata`.